# Inject parameters to entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I encounter this issue a lot of times, but only until now do I want to learn the best way to do it.

Say I have an Image entity, it has a 'path' property, which stores the relative path to the image file. For example, an image has its 'path' as '20141129/123456789.jpg'.

In parameters.yml, I set the absolute path to the directory that stores image files. Like this:

```
image_dir: %user_static%/images/galery/
```

I want to add the method 'getFullPath()' to Image entity, inside which the 'image_dir' parameter will be concatenated with 'path' property. I don't want to do the concatenation in controllers because I will be using it a lot. Also I don't want to insert image dir into Image's 'path' property, because I may change the image dir path later (which means I'll have to update the 'path' of all images in database).

So how can I inject the parameter into Image entity, so that getFullPath() can use it? Since Image entities will be fetched by repository methods instead of creating a new instance of Image, passing variables to construction method won't work.

Or is there a more elegant approach? I just want Image entities to have getFullPath() method, and I will be fetching images via both repository methods (find, findBy...) and query builder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could listen to the doctrine `postLoad` event and set the image directory in that so that when you later call `getFullPath()` it can return the concatenated string of the image directory and the path.

<kbd>postLoad listener</kbd>

```
namespace Acme\ImageBundle\Doctrine\EventSubscriber;

use Acme\ImageBundle\Model\ImageInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class ImageDirectorySubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    protected $imageDirectory;

    public function __construct($imageDirectory)
    {
        $this->imageDirectory = $imageDirectory;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::postLoad,
        );
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $image = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$image instanceof ImageInterface) {
            return;
        }

        $image->setImageDirectory($this->imageDirectory);
    }
}
```

<kbd>services.yml</kbd>

```
parameters:
    acme_image.subscriber.doctrine.image_directory.class:
            Acme\ImageBundle\Doctrine\EventSubscriber\ImageDirectorySubscriber

services:
    acme_image.subscriber.doctrine.image_directory:
        class: %acme_image.subscriber.doctrine.image_directory.class%
        arguments:
            - %acme_image.image_directory%
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

<kbd>Image Model</kbd>

```
class Image implements ImageInterface
{
    protected $path;

    protected $imageDirectory;

    .. getter and setter for path..

    public function setImageDirectory($imageDirectory)
    {
        // Remove trailing slash if exists
        $this->imageDirectory = rtrim($imageDirectory, '/');

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFullPath()
    {
        return sprintf('%s/%s', $this->imageDirectory, $this->path);
    }
}
```

Comment: postLoad Listener/Subscriber is it. I was too lazy for too long to do it right :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Qoop's approach is to make an image manager service and do the path stuff in it.  The code will be a bit simpler.

```
class ImageManager
{
    public function __construct($imageDirectory)
    {
        $this->imageDirectory = $imageDirectory;
    }
    public function getFullPath($image)
    {
        return $this->imageDirectory . $image->getPath();
    }
}

// Controller
$imageManager = $this->get('image_manager');

echo $imageManager->getFullPath($image);
```

It's a trade off.  Explicitly managing images vs using "behind the scenes" events.

Comment: This approach is indeed simpler & less code to begin with, but when included in dozens of places, you'll end up with more code than using event (written only once) & a native Image method. Besides we can't use it in twig! But for simple (& right) cases I guess it's still useful. Thanks.